# Changing base currency to Dollar According to Geo IP

Tags: currency, magento-1.7

how can the base currency be changed to US dollar if visitors country is not India.
there must be some easy way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up website pricing and have two websites each with their own base currency, except you need to update the prices manually in both website views as the updates are not automatic.

Comment: doesn't seems good, could you elaborate me more about two websites concept